# ArcGIS MapOptions and Layer on Android

Tags: android, arcgis, layer

I am new with ArcGIS and doing this [Base map](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/guide/use-arcgis-basemaps.htm), everything is ok and is working.
But when i want to add a layer, for example:

`ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer tms = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");`

It is not more possible to change MapView options, from street to gray, or topographics. Because it still shows me the Street map from the layer.

So, what i need to do to change map options with layer?